# Check if record from table exist then update or insert

Tags: sql-server

I have a lot of tables that needed to merge but first I need to check if Student already in the table

```
Table 1 (English)

FirstName   LastName   BirthDate   English
Kyle        Fernandez  01/05/2002  82
Bill        Cruz       08/24/2003  88


Table 2 (Math)
FirstName   LastName   BirthDate   Math
Kyle        Fernandez  01/05/2002  79
Bill        Cruz       08/24/2003  83
Mae         Sol        03/26/2002  87
```

Now what I need to do is merge those tables without repeating the same student. like this

```
Table Report Card
FirstName   LastName   BirthDate   English   Math
Kyle        Fernandez  01/05/2002  82        79
Bill        Cruz       08/24/2003  88        83
Mae         Sol        03/26/2002  0         87
```

I need to insert and update in bulk. Thank you

Comment: Did you try searching? There is a `merge` statement in SQL Server for this purpose. Whether it exists in your unknown version is a different question, but if it doesn't, that is answered too. Either search for the existing questions on this, or show an actual question, i.e. what you have tried and what was wrong with it. There is no question here, just an "I need" statement.

Comment: @underscore_d Thank you. I will try. It's my first encountering this problem and I needed some keywords from experts to start my research when I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a full outer join here:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.FirstName, t2.FirstName) AS FirstName,
    COALESCE(t1.LastName,  t2.LastName)  AS LastName,
    COALESCE(t1.Birthdate, t2.Birthdate) AS Birthdate,
    COALESCE(t1.English, 0) AS English,
    COALESCE(t2.Math, 0) AS Math
FROM Table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.FirstName = t1.FirstName AND
       t2.LastName = t1.LastName
```

The logic here is to retain a student even if it only appears in one, but not both, of the two tables.  We report the English and math scores as zero in the case where a given student does not have any value in either table.